# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'subString'

Tags: flutter

I'm unable to find solutions for this question, My error is string has no instances with Sub-string.
i want to print variable 'now' but it showing this error.I tried so many solution that matches this question but it didn't help me out.please help me out
Error:
E/flutter ( 6091): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'SubString'.
E/flutter ( 6091): Receiver: "+01:00"
E/flutter ( 6091): Tried calling: subString(1, 3)
E/flutter ( 6091): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 6091): #1      _LoadingState.getTime (package:world_time/pages/loading.dart:22:40)
E/flutter ( 6091):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {


  void getTime() async {
    //make the request
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London'));
    Map data =jsonDecode(response.body);
    //print(data);

    //get property from data
    String datetime =data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].subString(1,3);
    //print(datetime);
    //print(offset);

    //create a datetime object
    DateTime now =DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now =now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
    print(now);




  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('loading screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's `substring`, not `subString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
String offset = data['utc_offset'].toString().substring(1,3);
```